# How to get csv charset or CSVFormat from file?

Tags: java, csv

Using Apache Commons CSV,

Consider I can read both the Default and the Excel formats. The default uses "UTF-8" chartset and Excel format uses "windows-1252" charset.

I think there is no way in Apache Commons CSV to get which format the file is. How can I get which one is coming so I can read the right charset?

I tried to google for this but didn't find anywhere.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Firstly, it's more likely that the 'Excel format' uses UTF-8 since it's associated with an application. I'm not sure why a pure csv file (just a text file) would be associated with a particular charset such as Windows-1252. The format of a csv file is whatever charset created it

Comment: "How can I get which one is coming ...", you can't, as long the origin don't tell you what encoding is the data. Without the encoding given it is a bunch of "bytes". You may [guess](https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/guess_encoding.html), what encoding it is.

Comment: A unicode file might start with a BOM but not necessarily

Comment: @g00se the Excel format uses windows-1252, maybe because my primary language is portuguese, but that's how it is

Comment: @PeterMmm I thought so, csv is too simple, thank you anyway